# Dynamic memory allocation of 2d arrays that are in the struct

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct, multidimensional-array

I have a struct and I am finding the beginning and end of the lines in an image and in those lines beginning and end of the word, letter etc. (Implementing a basic OCR.)

```
typedef struct _IMAGE {
    int row; 
    int col; 
    int max_value;
    int **line;
    int **space;
    int **word;
    int **letter;
    int **matrix;//holds the image pixels
} IMAGE;
```

I want to alter my code with dynamically allocated matrices. But since I don't know how many lines and words that will be I don't know the size at the beginning so cannot do simple dynamic allocation. Do you recommend for me to use vectors in this situation? If so how should I use it?

Comment: You should use vectors, yes. You can emulate 2D variable size arrays with vector of vectors.

Comment: Question... Do the number of columns in line, space, word, etc... need to change after their first allocation?

Comment: @gd1 no columns will be the same only the rows will change for example **line has 2 colums fist indicating where the corresponding line begins and second indicating where it ends.

Comment: Line having two columns is bad. Create a structure Line { int start, int end } and put it all these structs a 1-d array.

Comment: @gd1 I created it like for example letter has 4 columns firs indicates which line it is in , second for which word and 3rd and 4th are the beginning and ending places of the letter.

Comment: When you design an array in which each element has a different meaning depending on its position, and the elements are few, I think it is better to devise an appropriate struct.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions on how I shold design it in the first place. But I'm afraid after this point It doesn't seem possible for me to change the whole code. So What I asked is that in such structure how should I use vectors for example first reserve some space and then resize it etc?

Answer (score 1):

You clarified in a comment that the number of columns in the 2D arrays will be constant, whereas the number of rows can change.

Therefore, you can use 1D vectors and address the elements by mapping the `(i, j)` indexes to a single  index with the formula: `k = i * number_of_columns + j`.

However, you said that the `line` array will have only 2 columns, one for the beginning o the line and one for the end. This makes me think that it is more convenient (especially for semantics) to have a `Line` struct/class with two fields (start, end) and put instances of this struct/class into a simple 1D vector.

When you design an array in which each element has a different meaning *depending on its position*, and the elements are few, I think it is better to devise an appropriate struct.

Last, since this is C++, you can declare structs in this way:

```
struct X
{
    int a;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No professional image library out there holds image data in a matrix. You should simply do:

```
struct Image
{
  int col;
  std::vector<int> matrix;
};
```

And access the pixels like `matrix[x+ col* y]`. That will be the quickest, most memory-friendly layout for pixel data. Or use an already existing image struct to avoid the concept of [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here).

Comment: I don't think the formula is correct. Example: 1 rows, 3 cols array. I want to access element `(0, 2)`, you access element `x + cols * y = 0 + 3 * 2 = 6`. Moreover, I think the OP is deliberately re-inventing the wheel for learning purposes. :)

Comment: @gd1 very well, then I will leave the off-by-one error there as an exercise for the reader.